# Table view with custom cell / image and label

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

how is the best way to fill a table view (custom cell) with a e.g. a selected image from camera roll and a user defined text in a text field? and how it can be saved?

Dictionary? Array? ....?

Comment: can you please give more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the image property, and tableview outlet in .h file.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIIImage *photoImage;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
```

in .m file in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: method:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image;
    image = (UIImage *)
    [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.photoImage = image;
    [self.tableView reloadData]; //call reloadData method to load data with image
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.movieTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
   cell.imageView.image = self.photoImage; 
   or use array and add image to array in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: and use the image

   cell.imageView.image = [self.photoArray objectAtIndex:0]; 

}
```

This will help you :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below format.

Array of Dictionary.
Array contains multiple dictionary and each dictionary contains your data like image reference and text message

May be this would be good format to store data